# How and when Gayatri mantra became public chant?

Tags: mantras, belief, meditation, gayatri-mantra, vedic-chanting

When i had Brahmopadesham, it was taught to us secretly in ears ensuring others and especially women don't listen to it. Women those times were closing the ears if someone starts chanting. Its powerful mantra and even evils don't come near who chants that.

But all of a sudden one day i started hearing from audio cassettes sung by ladies. I am not discriminating the gender bias here, but understanding if its really doable or it is just trying to break hindu mythologies in the name of secularism?

It was kept secret with in a group of people. By breaking this rule and thus by this, i believe the value of this mantra is taken for granted, people chant it wearing shoes even in xyz places now. What is the real use of going public and who was behind this?

Comment: Advent of the printing press meant that nobody could claim monopoly over knowledge anymore. Besides organizations like the Arya Samaj were responsible for making the study of the Vedas popular amongst non-Brahmins.

Comment: see my comments on this [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56120/what-happens-if-one-imparts-knowledge-where-he-is-not-supposed-to#comment170624_56120)