# What happens if one imparts knowledge where he is not supposed to?

Tags: vedas, karma, prayaschitta

The Manusmriti 2.112 says:

> धर्मार्थौ यत्र न स्यातां शुश्रूषा वाऽपि तद्विधा ।
> तत्र विद्या न वप्तव्या शुभं बीजमिवौषरे ॥ ११२ ॥
>
> Where merit and wealth are not possible, nor is there an adequate desire to serve, there knowledge should not be imparted; just as healthy seed (is not sown) on barren land.—(112)

Also the same goes with imparting knowledge to ignorant people and non-believers.

**Question:**

1. What **all** happens when one imparts knowledge to forbidden categories of people? 
   (One verse in the Manusmriti says that such a person goes to Naraka. Besides that what are the other effects? Like some say, one forgets such knowledge, etc.)
2. Does the same apply in case of inadvertently reciting the knowledge and someone unfit hearing it?
3. What is the prayashchitta one can do in case such a blunder has been committed?

---

Any source Pauranika smarta tantrika Vedic will be acceptable, but please list out all the effects.

Comment: what a strange Qn to ask in this age, when the vedas, their translations/commentaries are available for the whole world to consume.  Western scholars have played a crucial role in putting together critical editions of Mahabharata etc, @adiyarkku

Comment: It's not just a case of sowing on barren land, but sowing on poisonous land. Western scholars, in the name of translation, have done 10% good, and 90% damage. Scriptures are supposed to be taught and read by people who practice said scriptures, are in right character of satvik mind, have undertaken bonafide tapasya, and receptive to the truth, be it sweet or bitter. Most people are not. Hence, Bhagavan says in Gita to not impart this wisdom to those who don't have these traits. He is referring to the most secret parts of Gita, not common ones, like Gita has 18 chapters or Arjuna was an archer

Comment: It is common knowledge of karma that any person who commits a sin has to either repent to reduce his punishment, or undergo punishment. One such repentance is to chant mantras - thereby transferring his punishment to the devata in charge of that mantra. But it's not free. This is just like a school making parents pay for their child that broke a window while playing ball. Parents take on the responsibility, and in turn they get to discipline the child how they see fit. Similarly, the devata can discipline or expect favors from the chanter like puja. so far so good ?

Comment: Parents only raise THEIR children (mostly), not random ones. However devatas are responsible to protect ANYONE who chants the mantra (correctly). Therefore they have to take care to impart the mantra only to those who they believe won't abuse it, and those whose transgressions are within the devata's power to absolve. If a child set the entire school on fire, the parents won't be able to pay for it. So they will ensure the child doesn't get a flamethrower for their birthday. Now, the responsibility of imparting mantras is given to a guru/acharya - who has to 'vet' and 'test' the students.

Comment: If the guru imparts the mantra to a student, that guru then takes on all the responsibility of the student's sins. Imagine gayatri mantra being broadcast on speakers or youtube, heard and recited by any varna or linga. You want to know what happens when randos hear it ? there is a 1985 Tamil movie called Raja Rishi Vishvamitra. In it they say the term **'gayatri' was created from the tamil words 'kayam' (body) and 'thiri' (wick)** - he sacrificed his body as a wick, therefore it is called kayathhiri. This is exactly why we should not be ashamed to hold back knowledge from the undeserving.

Comment: the person who uploaded the secret mantras to youtube for the whole world to hear, unfortunately, has to take on the sins of everyone who hears/repeats it. of course, if they have enough tapasya in their account, good for them, go to town !

Comment: Vedas were not supposed to be transcribed. The tradition was to pass it down orally. When it is available in written form it easily gets into the hands of undeserving who will provide their own spin. Anyways now it can only be undone by act of bhagwan