# Protection from Kalki's wrath and re-establishment of Varnashrama

Tags: bhagavata-purana, kali-yuga, kalki, varnashrama, krita-yuga

As discussed here: [Definition and ritualistc rights of vrAtyas in the present day](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56678/definition-and-ritualistc-rights-of-vratyas-in-the-present-day), it is clear that there are no pure Kshatriyas and Vaisyas today (there may have been at the start of Kali, but definitely not in the 21st century).

In the Kalki Purana, it is mentioned: "At the end of Kali-yuga, the Supreme Lord, Hari, will incarnate as Lord Kalki and kill all the mlecchas, yavanas, atheists, and Buddhists of the world that defy the Vedic authority"

My questions are:

1. How does Buddhism play into this? **Why is the Lord so angry at Buddhists specifically if there are so many other mathAs that are Avaidika** (ex: Jainism, Islam, Chrsitianity, tribal religions, etc)? **Could these be interpolated prior to Adi SankarachArya when Buddhism was on the rise?**
2. **How do the current middle varnas (i.e., those passing themselves off as kshatriyas and vaisyAs, see link to question above) protect their lineage from the wrath of Kalki?** It is said that He will exterminate those who are "un-Aryan", but as discussed in the previous answer above, everybody except for select bramhana families have had some sort of varna sAnkaryam and thus "mlecchatva", even if they do not want to admit it. **If they (fallen dwijAs) continue to perform upanayanAs and pass themselves off as ksahtriyas and Vaishyas until that time, this means that they are unknowingly defying Vedic authority. Does that necessitate that their biological lineage will all be killed by Kalki? Or would Kalki try explaining that they are to follow the sUdra dharma instead?**
3. **How would Kalki re-etablish varnAshrama in satya-yuga if pretty much only a handful of sath brAmhana families would remain?** There already are no  pure seminal kshatriyas or vaisyAs.
4. Let us suppose after Kalki, certain Thenkalai Vaishnava AcharyAs and the Bhagavatham ([https://indiafacts.org/understanding-the-concept-of-varna-as-it-appears-in-hindu-scriptures-ii/#:~:text=Bhagavata%20Purana%2C%20one%20of%20the,10](https://indiafacts.org/understanding-the-concept-of-varna-as-it-appears-in-hindu-scriptures-ii/#:%7E:text=Bhagavata%20Purana%2C%20one%20of%20the,10)) are accurate in their statements of the Hamsa Varna in the Satya Yuga. **If the chAthurvarna is created every cycle from a Hamsa Varna which solely meditated "on the pranavA", then why would SwAyambhavu Manu reveal the Manu Smriti during his first Satya Yuga?**
5. The Manu Smriti talks of places that are considered to be "Arya Varta": https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145592.html . It also speaks of "fallen dwijAs" such as the YavanAs, drAvidAs, etc. **If SwAyambhu ManU is the first Manu, how were these tribes and places already in vogue? How are they already fallen? Are they re-created by Kalki after His re-establishment of dharmA or is it that Manu edits the sAstra prior to each chathuryugA?**

Note: I mean no offense to anyone. This question is purely to understand the implications of sAstra in today's context and rituals; examples with references were provided to better frame the question.

May the Vedic Dharma and everyone in BhAratha flourish.

Answer (score 2):

> My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults, there is still
> one good quality about this age: Simply by chanting the **Hare Kṛṣṇa
> mahā-mantra, one can become free from material bondage and be promoted
> to the transcendental kingdom**

Srimad bhagvatam12.3.51

> Persons who are strongly entrapped by the consciousness of enjoying
> material life, and who have therefore accepted as their leader or guru
> a similar blind man attached to external sense objects, cannot
> understand that the goal of life is to return home, back to Godhead,
> and engage in the service of Lord Viṣṇu. **As blind men guided by
> another blind man miss the right path and fall into a ditch,**
> ***materially attached men led by another materially attached man are
> bound by the ropes of fruitive labor, which are made of very strong
> cords, and they continue again and again in materialistic life,
> suffering the threefold miseries.***

Srimad bhagvatam 7.5.31

I would also add my thoughts in answers

1. Kalki will fight for righteousness, not for anger as it is written in gita he comes in every yuga for the eradication of evil. Now, all those in other religion and praying to other gods. Can be atmost satvic but not in bhakti yog.

BG 9.25: ***Worshippers of the celestial gods take birth amongst the celestial gods, worshippers of the ancestors go to the ancestors, worshippers of ghosts take birth amongst such beings, and My devotees come to Me alone.***

So likewise in kaliyug other religion come according to bhavishya puran and those worship other than him. Will face consequence of it. You may ask why? Answer is many good thoughts in other religion will be vanished till that time and only tamsic devotion will remain so that's the reason(note tamsic is not equal to tantric)

2)

---

```
> Manu Smriti 2.157 states that "By virtue (of their actions), they who
> were Sudras in a former life become Brahmanas in this (life); even so,
> they who were Brahmanas in a former life, may become (Sudras) in this
> world."
```

---

*Manu Smriti 10.65 states that "Know that a man becomes a Brahmana not by his plaited hair, not by his family, not by birth. He is a Brahmana who has gained knowledge (of Brahman). In his conduct, he is the embodiment of truth, austerity, and compassion."*

These verses suggest that a person's caste is not solely determined by birth but by their actions, behavior, and knowledge.

"***Time causes all distinctions to disappear;* it is said that in a time of distress**, everything may be obtained by one of any class, the Brahmana by his knowledge of the Veda, the Kshatriya by his energy, the Vaisya by his wealth, and the Sudra by his labor." (Vishnu Purana 3.11.4)

Kaliyug is equally synonymous with time of distress.
"In times of distress, every man is himself; proficiency is destroyed in the case of a Brahmana (who is a survivor of a disaster); wrestling, in the case of a Kshatriya; trade, in the case of a Vaishya; and service, in the case of a Shudra." (Matsya Purana 215.23)

3)

> tatraaiike mahaabaaho sarvaagnya sarvadarshana sarva shastra
> vihinnyaasi aanartasheemakhaanapi
>
> Translation: "In Kalki Avatar, the great soul Lord Vishnu will appear
> and he will be an expert in all weapons, with all knowledge, able to
> perceive everything, omniscient, and all-knowing. He will remove all
> the iniquities and maladies of the world."

> Matsya Purana, Chapter 47, Verses 23-25
>
> varnasramavadhirajas tu kalkir-ityudiritah sarvajna sarvatomukho na
> bhuto na bhavishyati
>
> Translation: "Kalki, who will be the ruler of the Varnashram system,
> will be all-knowing, all-pervading, and will exist everywhere and at
> all times, past, present, and future."

So one who is all knowing and all powerful can do anything. It make no sense doubting him

Last things vedas won't be edited in any chaturyuga but stories, epics and avtars will have slight  variation in every yug

Also, many things/events and characters***should not be taken literally while reading purans, it has symbolic meaning.***
You can disagree with my thoughts so I have included verses

Comment: Would be better if you show reference from puran in question

Comment: May I ask why you're commenting under your own post as if you were addressing a different user?

Comment: Because I have not read kalki puran and that's not part of answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Adishankaracharya ; I appreciate the verses as well. It is just that certain peetAdhipathis themselves take it so literally that I get confused on how strict we are to be with certain things. So pretty much, the dharma for the majority of us is to just follow the rituals that is being handed down to our families and teach the next generation to be devoted to Narayana, true bramhanas and the Vedic religion. There is so much sAnkarya already that the people doing honor killings in the name of maintaining blood purity cannot be encouraged, correct?

Comment: @Adishankaracharya could you post the links to those verses? I am not able to find the exact slokAs online from the purAnAs.

Answer (score 0):

Shri Kalki will kill all evildoers, regardless of their caste.
In Bhagavata Purana (Part/Canto 12) it has been mentioned that (almost) everyone in this age will be barbaric and like a Shudra. This means that those who behave good are considered like Brahmana.

When Shri Kalki arrives, only the pure devotees and good karmis will remain, rest all other wrong doers and other religions except Hinduism will be wiped off.