# regulations in Kali Yuga regarding hearing the vEda

Tags: vedas, dharma-shastras, women, kali-yuga, shruti

It is discussed in the question here: [Definition and ritualistc rights of vrAtyas in the present day](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56678/definition-and-ritualistc-rights-of-vratyas-in-the-present-day) that mostly everyone except the brAmhanas are vrAtyas (and thus entitled to the rights of sUdras).

1. **How are brAmhanas to reconcile sAstric injunction to not perform yajnAs for sUdras or recite the vEdas in front of them?** Virtually no one would have yarns performed. **Could this mean specifically the Vedic yajnAs** (i.e., the purAnik/tantrik hOmas are fair game)?
2. For the women and sUdras (who compromise 99% of the population), how **are they to perform prAyaschitta for listening to the srutI?** There are many noble women, Hindus, AstikAs of mlEccha birth, etc who refrain from reciting but listen to the vEdas (Ex: Pancha sukthAs on Youtube, Mantras) to purify their homes, etc. **Are they to stop listening to mantrAs in the temple, etc and “pour molten lead in their ears” or is that merely an arthavAdha to prevent ineligible people from memorizing the vEda?**

Note: I mean no offense to anyone. This question is purely to understand the implications of sAstra in today's context and rituals; examples with references were provided to better frame the question.

May the Vedic Dharma and everyone in BhAratha flourish.

Comment: @mar, hoping you can weigh in on your opinion with sAstric knowledge.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @Ikshvaku : was wondering if you all could weigh in as well on these Qs. Only if you have time, Thank you.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ,

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru