# If a person reverts back to sanatan dharma which varna does he belong

Tags: manu-smriti, varna, varnashrama

***If a person do gharwapsi to sanatan dharma which varna does he belong***
Quote with scriptures
Or his daily work will determine the varna??

Comment: The point of whole Verna is that it is decided by the gunas by a master who initiates him.

Comment: It depends on how you define the term 'returning back to Sanatana dharma'. In case of those who committed apostasy (i.e were born as a practising Hindu, but left the faith due to various reasons), if they return back, then they also regain back their previous Varna. However if you subscribe to the modern politically created doctrine of 'ghar-wapsi', then due to the lack of wearing yajñopavīta, these converts are to be treated as śūdras. Before you become offended at designation of the term śūdra, I suggest you to read this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56691/22857

Comment: Regarding interaction of these converts with other Hindus, there is a little controversy. In this regard, the interaction of the Ahom tribe with Hindus can be taken as a case study. The Ahom tribe migrated from China's Yunnan province into Assam's Brahmaputra Valley around the 13th century & slowly consolidated their power throughout NE India. Due to their living alongside Hindus, the Ahoms gradually adopted Hindu culture & religion.

Comment: Since the Ahom kings had effectively repelled attacks of Muslims from Bengal Sultanate (& later the Mughal Empire), the Ahoms were treated as a touchable Hindu caste by the other Assamese Hindus. However, outside Assam, the Ahoms have faced discrimination from other Hindus due to their Sinitic facial features.

Comment: The Shankaracharya of Puri even goes father, he advocates that Hindus shouldn't establish the relation of 'roti-beti' with new converts, which means that he wants the new converts to be treated as untouchables.